# Join columns to rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Suppose you have a table *Table1* with columns

> UserId, Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6, Item7, Item8, Item9, Item10

and you have another table *Table2* with

> UserId, ItemId, Name

. The values in *Table1* is the ItemId from *Table2*. I have a need to display

> UserId, ItemId, Name

where Item1 is 1st and Item10 is last and you have 10 rows. In other words, Item1 is 1st row and Item10 is last row. If there's any way to avoid CASE WHEN that would be great. I may have more columns in the future and would hate to hardcode the 10 columns.

Comment: What's the point of table1 if table2 already has all the needed information? Is it just for ordering the items in Tabl2? If so, why isn't there just a column for the order?

Comment: Table1 comes from AzureML Recommendation engine. I have no control in how it outputs the data. So for every user, it creates 10 recommended items. I need to display those recommendations on the screen based off of my Table2. Item1 in Table 1 is the most recommended one and Item10 is the least recommended one. Hope it clears it up.

Comment: Is this a MachineLearning or TSQL question? Why did you mention ML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a *reverse pivot* in this case.  You don't use CASE, like you would in a normal pivot, but instead `UNION ALL`, like this:

```
select Table1.UserId, Table2.ItemId, Table2.Name
from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.Item1 = Table2.ItemId
UNION ALL
select Table1.UserId, Table2.ItemId, Table2.Name
from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.Item2 = Table2.ItemId
UNION ALL
...
select Table1.UserId, Table2.ItemId, Table2.Name
from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.Item10 = Table2.ItemId
```

If you have more items, you should also be able to write a snippet that generates the repeating `UNION ALL` syntax so you don't have to type it all by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Given you can bypass doing it entirely with SQL, I would highly recommend using e.g. R or Python to process transactions in a ML useable way. The tidyr package with the gather function does exactly what you want to do.

Another way is to crosstabulate. It´s absolutely fine deriving a solution with the SQL standard, but a lot of problems can be much easier done within R or Python.

Comment: I agree, I have a sql writer right now but am finding no documentation how to use the gather function or the tidyr package so I'm resorting to sql even though I totally agree.

Answer (score 0):

A table1 with just 3 columns

```
userid, itemid, sequence
```

would be more conducive for your purposes. You would be required to convert your AzureML output from the single line

```
Uid1, itm1,itm2,itm3,...,itm10
```

into 10 lines like

```
Uid1, itm1, 1
Uid1, itm2, 2
Uid1, itm3, 3
...
Uid1, itm10,10
```

Assuming you get the above output line as a (temporary) table output from AzureML with name `tbla` you could use the follwing `UNION ALL` construct (as suggested by Spencer Simpson):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (userid, itemid, sequence)
SELECT uid, itm1, 1 FROM tbla UNION ALL
SELECT uid, itm2, 2 FROM tbla UNION ALL
SELECT uid, itm3, 3 FROM tbla UNION ALL
SELECT uid, itm4, 4 FROM tbla UNION ALL
...
SELECT uid, itm10, 10 FROM tbla
```

To store the information into `table1` which will be the only table you will have to deal with. No `JOIN`s will be required anymore.

**Note:** I am not quite sure what your column `name` relates to. Is it the name of an item or the name of a user?

In both cases there should be a second table `table2` that takes care of the correspondence between `name` and `userid`/`itemid` like

```
itm/usr   name
```

This table will then be `join`-ed into any query that requires displaying the `name` column too.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to work around this was to use Python (or R) and use the `melt` function.
There is also a `pivot_table` function in the dataframe.

So, you can have your columns be converted to rows.  Then join those rows on the other table.

[Reshaping and Pivot Tables](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt)